# Django DRF - Axios POST

Tags: reactjs, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am converting my app from jQuery/Ajax to ReactJs.
Currently in the backend I am grabbing an array by doing

```
request.data.getlist('something[])
```

With the same code when I am doing an axios POST i get an error. If I change the code to `request.data['something']` then it works fine. What am I missing? How can I grab an array of string that working for both ajax and axios

-SOLVED-

I just updated the backend to handle both cases ( as I currently need ) for some reason when I grab the array from ajax request is slightly different then grabbing the array from axios.

Comment: Can you show us what the server response is?

Comment: request.data.getlist('something'[]) actually returns an error : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'getlist' on a POST with Axios but same code/data with Ajax creates the obj as expected

Comment: is axios sending the data in json format?

Comment: yes, axios sends data in json as default